# Convert HTML SVG to JSON

Tags: javascript, php, json, svg

I have SVG code and I want to convert it in JSON file.

Here is my SVG code:

```
<svg height="400" version="1.1" width="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
<image x="-50" y="0" width="500" height="450" preserveAspectRatio="none" a0:href="style/images/products/t-shirts/Gildan_2000/any-quantity/Gildan_2000_White_Front.jpg" xmlns:a0="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"/>
<desc>Created with Raphaël 2.1.0</desc><defs/>
<rect x="110" y="55" width="190" height="255" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="none" stroke="#a0a0a0" style="display: none;"/>
<rect x="110" y="310" width="190" height="30" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#a0a0a0" stroke="#000" style="fill-opacity: 0.5; display: none;" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="0.5"/>
<text style="text-anchor: middle; font: 12px &quot;Arial&quot;; display: none;" x="205" y="325" text-anchor="middle" font="10px &quot;Arial&quot;" stroke="none" fill="#ffffff" font-size="12px">
<tspan dy="5">საბეჭდი არე</tspan>
</text>
<path style="display: none;" fill="none" stroke="#52d3fe" d="M200,0L200,420"/>
<path style="display: none;" fill="none" stroke="#52d3fe" d="M0,170L410,170"/>
<rect x="185" y="450" width="150" height="20" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#a0a0a0" stroke="#000" style="fill-opacity: 0.5; display: none;" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="0.5"/>
</svg>
```

I what to convert this string into JSON file and then load.
This is T-Shirt design code.

How to do it with JavaScript or PHP code?
I saw some examples but nothing work for me.

Thanks.

I want to convert it like this:

```
{
"images" :[
            {
                "src" : "style/images/tee-templates/military/plane.png",
                "x" : "135",
                "y" : "115",
                "width" : "130",
                "height" : "56",
                "params" : { "transform" : "" }
            }
        ],
"texts" :[
            {
                "title" : "Property of",
                "x" : "200",
                "y" : "100",
                "params" : {
                                "font-family" : "collegebold", 
                                "font-size" : "20", 
                                "fill" : "#000000", 
                                "stroke" : "#000000", 
                                "stroke-width" : 0,
                                "transform" : ""                                
                            }
            },
            {
                "title" : "U.S. Military",
                "x" : "200",
                "y" : "200",
                "params" : {
                                "font-family" : "fascinate_inlineregular", 
                                "font-size" : "25", 
                                "fill" : "#000000", 
                                "stroke" : "#000000", 
                                "stroke-width" : 0,
                                "transform" : ""                                
                            }
            }               
        ]
}
```

Comment: JSON? Any JSON? Like, e.g. `{"data":"<svg height=\"400\" version=\"1.1\" width=\"400\"..."}`?

Comment: Convert to JSON? Do you know what JSON is?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/yui-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/webtoolkit.base64.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ObjTree.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jkl-dumper.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

YUI().use("node", "event", "io", "json-parse", function (Y) {

    Y.on("domready", function (e) {

        Y.one("#example").on("click", function(e) {
            Y.one("#xml").set("value", Y.io("example.xml", {sync: true}).responseText);
        });

        Y.one("#tojson").on("click", function(e) {
            var xotree = new XML.ObjTree();
            var dumper = new JKL.Dumper(); 
            var tree = xotree.parseXML(Y.one("#xml").get("value"));
            Y.one("#json").set("value", dumper.dump(tree));
        });

        Y.one("#toxml").on("click", function(e) {
            var xotree = new XML.ObjTree();
            var json = eval("(" + Y.one("#json").get("value") + ")");
            Y.one("#xml").set("value", formatXml(xotree.writeXML(json))); 
        });

        Y.one("#save").on("click", function(e) {
            var cfg = {
                method: "POST",
                sync: true,
                headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json" },
                data: "{ 'xml': '" + Base64.encode(Y.one("#xml").get("value")) + 
                    "', 'json': '" + Base64.encode(Y.one("#json").get("value")) + "'}"
            };
            var response = Y.io("/backend/share/save", cfg);
            if (response.status == 200) {
                var base = window.location.href.split('#')[0];
                base = base.split('?')[0];
                var url = base + "?save=" + response.responseText;
                Y.one("#saveurl").setHTML(url);
                Y.one("#saveurl").set("href", url);
                Y.one("#savewrap").removeClass("hide");
            } else if (response.status == 400) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            } else {
                alert("Internal Server Error: " + response.responseText);
            }
        });

        var save = getParameterByName("save");
        if (save != undefined) {
            var cfg = { sync: true };
            var response = Y.io("/backend/share/retrieve?name=" + save, cfg);
            if (response.status == 200) {
                var data = Y.JSON.parse(response.responseText);
                Y.one("#xml").set("value", Base64.decode(data.xml));
                Y.one("#json").set("value", Base64.decode(data.json));
            }
        }

    });

});

var formatXml = function (xml) {
    var reg = /(>)(<)(\/*)/g;
    var wsexp = / *(.*) +\n/g;
    var contexp = /(<.+>)(.+\n)/g;
    xml = xml.replace(reg, '$1\n$2$3').replace(wsexp, '$1\n').replace(contexp, '$1\n$2');
    var pad = 0;
    var formatted = '';
    var lines = xml.split('\n');
    var indent = 0;
    var lastType = 'other';
    // 4 types of tags - single, closing, opening, other (text, doctype, comment) - 4*4 = 16 transitions 
    var transitions = {
        'single->single': 0,
        'single->closing': -1,
        'single->opening': 0,
        'single->other': 0,
        'closing->single': 0,
        'closing->closing': -1,
        'closing->opening': 0,
        'closing->other': 0,
        'opening->single': 1,
        'opening->closing': 0,
        'opening->opening': 1,
        'opening->other': 1,
        'other->single': 0,
        'other->closing': -1,
        'other->opening': 0,
        'other->other': 0
    };

    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        var ln = lines[i];
        var single = Boolean(ln.match(/<.+\/>/)); // is this line a single tag? ex. <br />
        var closing = Boolean(ln.match(/<\/.+>/)); // is this a closing tag? ex. </a>
        var opening = Boolean(ln.match(/<[^!].*>/)); // is this even a tag (that's not <!something>)
        var type = single ? 'single' : closing ? 'closing' : opening ? 'opening' : 'other';
        var fromTo = lastType + '->' + type;
        lastType = type;
        var padding = '';

        indent += transitions[fromTo];
        for (var j = 0; j < indent; j++) {
            padding += '\t';
        }
        if (fromTo == 'opening->closing')
            formatted = formatted.substr(0, formatted.length - 1) + ln + '\n'; // substr removes line break (\n) from prev loop
        else
            formatted += padding + ln + '\n';
    }

    return formatted;
};

</script>
<div>
                <div class="cols">
                    <p>XML<a id="example">get example xml</a></p>
                    <div class="textareacontainer">

                        <textarea id="xml" rows="20" cols="20" wrap="off"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="cols colmid">
                    <input id="tojson" type="button" value="-->">
                    <input id="toxml" type="button" value="<--">
                </div>
                <div class="cols">
                    <p>JSON</p>
                    <div class="textareacontainer">

                        <textarea id="json" rows="20" cols="20" wrap="off"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Sorry i didn't quite understood what you mean.

Comment: Import Script Useing Raphael.json